# In OTP authentication through firebase in latest update it requires reCaptcha is there any way to bypass it in android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I tried to create OTP authentication through firebase but latest update requires to put dependency "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0" this open a neb web tab to verify reCaptcha before sending OTP. I don't want to let it open a new web tab for reCaptcha. Is there any way to bypass it?

Even i have tried to provide reCaptcha verification using safetynet in the app but it still opens new tab after the verification done by my code. Help me fix this issue.

[dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ISC6.png)

[this happens just before sending OTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgWdZ.png)

Comment: I did not find any solution to this, if this is a new "feature", there's no getting around it from the looks of it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reCAPTCHA flow you should enable SafetyNet for your project, follow below steps or you can also visit [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) for more info.

1. Go to google cloud console , select your project .
2. Click on navigation menu and select APis & services and then select Dashboard .
3. Click on enable api and services and enable api " Android Device Verification".
4. Add SHA 256 in firebase project settings.(debug and release both)
5. Download and replace the latest google-services.json file in your project.